# Determine whether or not these are valid operations.

Tags: group-theory

I'm reviewing for an exam and I would like to know if, my answers are valid.

$$ \ a*b=\sqrt{|ab|} \text{ on the set }   \Bbb Q$$
 $$ \text{Example: }   2*1=\sqrt{|1*2|} =\sqrt{2} \notin \Bbb Q $$
Therefore, this is not an operation on the set of rational numbers.

$$a*b=a\ln{b} \text{ on the set } \{x\in\Bbb R: x>0\}   $$
For this second operation, I'm going to show that the associative property is not going to hold i.e. $ (a*b)*c=a *(b*c). $

$$ \  (2*3)*4=2\ln{3}*4=2.2*4=2.2\ln{4}=3.05 $$
$$ 2*(3*4)=2*3\ln{4}=2*4.15=2\ln{4.15}=2.85$$
$$ (2*3)*4\neq 2*(3*4)$$

Therefore, this  is not an operation on the set of  real numbers because we have obtained different results.

$$ a*b=|a-b| \text{ on the set } \{n \in \Bbb Z: n \ge 0\}$$

$$ 4*5=|4-5|=1 \in \Bbb Z, \ \  5*4=|5-4|=1 \in \Bbb Z $$
$$ 5*0=|5-0|=5 \in  \Bbb Z, \ \ 0*5=|0-5|=5 \in \Bbb Z$$
$$ 5*5=|5-5|=0 \in \Bbb Z, \ \ then \ \  a=a^{-1}$$
$$ (4*3)*5=|4-3|*5=1*5=|1-4|=4 $$
$$ 4*(3*5)=4*|3-5|=4*2=|4-2|=2 $$
$$(4*3)*5\neq 4*(3*5)$$

Given that the other properties seem to hold, the associative property doesn't so, this is not a valid operation on the set of integers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you call a "valid operation". If you mean an associative operation which is closed with respect to the underlying set, then your results are correct. If the associativity is not relevant, your first calculation is ok. For the second one, note that $2 \ast \ln (1)  = 2 \cdot \ln(1) = 0 \leq 0$, so this is not an element of the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0 \}$.